# get diferent values for same timestamp postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have for the same timestamp 2 diferent types with a total value. I want to create a query which retrieves timestamp, value1, value2 where value1 is total of type1 and value2 is total of type2.

My sum field is a numeric [] but with just one value in the type i'm working on.. in the others cases is an array with different values.

I tried:

```
select distinct type, timestamp, sum 
from default_dataset 
where type like 'probing_%' 
group by type, timestamp, sum 
limit 10
```

Doing

```
select timestamp, type, sum 
from default_dataset 
where type like 'probing_%' 
order by timestamp desc 
limit 50
```

I have

```
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_repated | 50
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_live | 10
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_live | 15
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_repated | 10
2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_live | 11
2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_repeated | 40
2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_repeated | 21
2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_live | 26
```

I want a result like timestamp, type, sum(sum)

```
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_repated | 65
2017-07-13 12:24:38+01 | probing_live | 25

2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_live | 37
2017-07-13 12:19:00+01 | probing_repeated | 61
```

Anyone?

Comment: hint: `GROUP BY timestamp, type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try sum[1]?.. like this:

```
select timestamp, type, sum(sum[1])
from default_dataset 
where type like 'probing_%' 
group by "timestamp", "type" 
limit 50
```

and to make it all in one column, just conat the result:

```
with a as (
select timestamp a, type b, sum(sum[1]) c
from default_dataset 
where type like 'probing_%' 
group by "timestamp", "type" 
)
select concat(a,' ',b,' ',c) from a
```

Comment: column "default_dataset.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: try now. sorry cant myself - you dont give the DDL for the relation

Comment: What if I tried to do with inner joins? Something like...

select dd.timestamp, ddl.sum(sum[1]) as live,  ddr.sum(sum[1]) as repeated, ddp.sum(sum[1]) as passerBy from default_dataset dd 
inner join default_dataset ddl on ddl.timestamp=dd.timestamp and ddl.type='probing_live'
inner join default_dataset ddr on ddr.timestamp=dd.timestamp and ddr.type='probing_repeated'
inner join default_dataset ddp on ddp.timestamp=dd.timestamp and ddp.type='probing_passerBy' 
where dd.timestamp < DATE_TRUNC('second',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Comment: well, I dont see any benefit here with join. but If you see it, post a new question?

Comment: I was trying to get everything together, to simplify my data. I need to have a sctructure with timestamp totalType1, totalType2 understand.. how can i do that? The query you gave me get the data but separated

Comment: sorry. the query in my answer should give `I want a result like timestamp, type, sum(sum)` - do I miss something?

Comment: Everything in the same column, sorry